# Set a narrower UIRefreshControl's Refreshing Height

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol, uicontrol

When the `UIRefreshControl` is refreshing/animating, it has a height which seems to be `60` points. Is there anyway to make it narrower? I would like to make the height of the `UIRefreshControl` while it is animating to `44` points

Edit: The possible duplicate does not have a working solution and it was asked for ObjC

Comment: Comment on edit : It doesn't matter if it was asked in Objective C. The concept of subclass remains same for Swift.

Comment: Don't take this personally. Did you subclass UIRefreshControl and change the size as suggested in the answer which was upvoted ?

Comment: @Nitish yep, I even commented on that answer.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote. You were right, it didn't work. Check my answer below which I just tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Output without transform :**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate it. Slightly wonky/hacky since this changes the size of the loading indicators, but thankfully I am using a subview and countering it by scaling that back up.  I also observe the pull distance for activation will be reduced. At least it works!